# MS SQL Server и OLAP кубы. Отличие от выгрузки данных таблицы просто в сводную excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, olap

Возник следующий вопрос касательно использования OLAP-кубов.

### Исходные данные

Допустим на MS SQL Server есть информация вида **"Формат - Магазин - позиция - поставщик позиции- кол-во товара - день прихода товара-ответственный менеджер"**. Она хранится в нормализованном виде, соответственно, что бы получить описанный выше вид, необходимо объединить между собой несколько таблиц. Это объединение сохранено как представление.

### Задача

Необходимо выгрузить эту информацию в сводную таблицу, что бы пользователи могли сделать отчеты вида:

### а) Формат - позиция -сумма товара - дата

### б) Менеджер - формат - кол-во позиций - дата

### в)  Дата - формат - позиция - кол-во-поставщиков

### Варианты решения задача

Решить задачу можно двумя способами. Или через ODBC выгрузить представление напрямую в excel и обычным "обновить таблицу" пользователь сможет актуализировать данные. Либо сделать отчетность с помощью OLAP-куба. Результаты получаются одинаковые. Затраты для куба естественно больше.

### Суть вопроса

Поясните пожалуйста, действительно ли для данного примера не нужен OLAP-куб или я что-то упускаю? Как нужно дополнить исходные данные/требования к отчетам, что бы использование OLAP-куба стало оправданным?
Спасибо.

Comment: Смотря какой обьем даных. Обновление представления на 10 млн строк можна сделать только с помощью PowerPivot. Плюс время на обновление, а так же сводная таблица в excel не умеет distinct count только надстройка PowerPivot . А если даных на 1 млрд строк? Если даных мало, а очет надо быстро то первый способ ваш. А если вы планируете постоянные отчеты и большой объем даных тогда задумайтесь над проектированием кубов